# unix sendmail attchment not working

Tags: unix, sendmail

I have below script but it sends email without any attachment. What is wrong?

```
sendmail /A "/home/dd/data/list.txt" "dd@gmail.com" -t << EOF
To:dd@gmail.com
Subject:List of ids
This is the message
 [new line]
```

Everything else works as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The here document is not completed.

```
sendmail /A "/home/dd/data/list.txt" "dd@gmail.com" -t << -EOF
To:dd@gmail.com
Subject:List of ids
This is the message
EOF
```

try -EOF so the trailing EOF does not need to be in the leftmost column.

Try this, I just tested it:

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -tv me@myplace.com <<%%
Subject: test of sendmail
This is the note
$(uuencode attachment.file newname.txt)
%%
```

I did not have time to get back to this.  email address goes on line 1

Comment: This is causing EOF to appear in my message body. I had tried this option. But it does not help send the attachment.

Comment: Thanks @jim. But i got below error message and a email without attachment was sent. 
uuencode: not found [No such file or directory]
But when i do man uuencode I get the man pages for it

Comment: Then there is something else in your code/data that is causing a problem - like a filename with spaces.

Comment: I checked my /usr/sbin dir and and I don't see the uuencode. I think the software is not there..

Comment: The which command, among others, will show you where uuencode lives on your machine.  You may be forced to use base64 on some linux boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Try the script below:

```
#!/bin/sh
# send/include list.txt file after "here document" (email headers + start of email body)
cat - "/home/dd/data/list.txt" | /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -- "dd@gmail.com" <<END
To: dd@gmail.com
Subject: List of ids

This is the message
END
```

Comment: I just inadvertently edited your answer.  Please ignore the note from SO.  Sorry.